# Simple metric for blur in images?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I'm trying to tell if a given photo is blurry. I know that this is basically an impossible task, and that any metric will return undesirable results sometimes.

I'm wondering if there's a simple metric that at least tries to estimate blur that I can use though. Specifically, the task has a **high tolerance for false positives**. e.g. If I got something that eliminated 90% of blurry photos and 50% of non-blurry photos I would be very happy.

I'm trying to implement this in Java. I have an array of pixels (as ints). Please keep in mind I have a limited understanding of image processing techniques (fourier transforms, etc.), and I would love a very specific walkthrough of how to code a solution.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: Fair point, I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: There is no simple metric, but some success has been had using discrete wavelet transforms - [see this paper for example](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~htong/pdf/ICME04_tong.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

A very simple measure would be to apply a Sobel filter and investigate the overall energy of the filtered image. The more an image is blurred, the more edges vanish, the smaller the energy of the filtered image. Of course you'll run into problems with this approach when you try to determine a threshold for blurred vs. not blurred, but maybe this simple method will give you an idea.

Check wikipedia for the Sobel filter, and here is a code snippet to get out the edge ratio of an image. You can use these edge ratios to pair wise compare is images have more or less edges. Still, keep in mind that this is a simple approach and the answer of a.lasram is definitely correct.

```
    float[] sobelX = {
            -1, 0, 1,
            -2, 0, 2,
            -1, 0, 1,
    };
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));
    ColorConvertOp grayScaleOp = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
    BufferedImage grayImage = grayScaleOp.filter(image, null);
    BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp( new Kernel(3, 3, sobelX) );
    BufferedImage result = op.filter(grayImage, null);
    WritableRaster r = result.getRaster();
    int[] pixel = new int[r.getWidth()];
    double countEdgePixels = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y<r.getHeight();y++) {
        // System.out.println("y = " + y);
        r.getPixels(0, y, r.getWidth(),1, pixel);
        for (int i = 0; i < pixel.length; i++) {
            // create some stat out of the energy ...
            if (pixel[i] > 128) {
                countEdgePixels++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Edge pixel ratio = %4.4f\n", countEdgePixels/(double) (r.getWidth()*r.getHeight()));
    ImageIO.write(result, "png", new File("out.png"));
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've said you're not going to find a universal metric.

Also there are different types of blur: uniform, anisotropic, motion blur...

In general blurred images tend to exhibit low frequencies. A possible descriptor is the sum of magnitude of the k highest frequencies. Image with a low sum is likely to be blurred overall.

The magnitudes can be obtained in N*log(N) time using Fourier spectrum (high frequencies are far from the origin) or a [Laplace pyramid](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~hezy/Vision%20Seminar/pyramid83.pdf) (high frequencies correspond to the first scales).

[Wavelet](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/query/) transform is another possible descriptor

Comment: If it helps, the blur I'm interested in is motion blur.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late reply but worth for the next person that will bump in this question.

I found in Google Scholars several papers that talk about averaging the sum of all edges in the picture compared to the width of all of them, as can be seen in this two articles: [First](http://stefan.winklerbros.net/Publications/icip2002.pdf) and [Second](http://scien.stanford.edu/pages/labsite/2010/psych221/projects/2010/AdityaAnchuri/main.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I have an better idea: what if we solve vice versa task? If we find sharpness image then we gain opposite to blur metric.

Some of articles are here:

- [A Perceptual Image Sharpness Metric Based on Local Edge Gradient Analysis](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6469166)
- [A No-Reference Objective Image Sharpness Metric Based on the Notion of Just Noticeable Blur (JNB)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4799375)
- [Aberration correction by maximizing generalized sharpness metrics](https://opg.optica.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?uri=josaa-20-4-609)